# Can't use arrow keys to navigate in a tab group ONLY when NVDA is launched. Any solutions for this?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, nvda

The arrow keys navigation works fine when NVDA is off, but as soon as I open NVDA in the background I can't use it to navigate in tab groups.

Did you ever experience this and do you have any suggestions on how to resolve it? Thank you.

The role is set to 'presentation', I tried changing it to tablist and it does not work. Role 'tab' alters the entire navigation behavior of the tab group so I want to avoid that as the expected behavior is to navigate with left/right arrow keys.

Comment: The question needs some clarity. It seems you already got a good clue that the `role` might be the reason. What did you try to change the role? Did you also apply the `tab` and `tabpanel` roles?  It would be great if you could share some code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to have some code posted, otherwise we're just guessing.

When you <kbd>tab</kbd> to the tab navigator does the focus move to the tab that is selected within the group? (When <kbd>tabbing</kbd> to it the first time, I presume the first tab is selected.)  Once the tab navigator has focus, then you can use the left/right arrow keys to navigate to the other tabs (when NVDA is not running)?

(It's unfortunate that pattern is called a "tab" which is confusing when also talking about the <kbd>tab</kbd> key)

[image]

I would first start with making sure you're following the "[tab navigator](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabpanel/)" design pattern. If everything works as explained in that design pattern, in particular, the "[Keyboard Interaction](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabpanel/#keyboard-interaction-21)" section, then it sounds like you don't have the `roles` set on the right elements.

The behavior you're describing sounds like the left/right arrow keys are going to NVDA instead of to the tab navigator.  You didn't say what happens when you press left/right when NVDA is running.  Are characters read one by one?  That would definitely mean the left/right arrow keyboard events are going to NVDA.

If that's true, then you don't have the [`role="tablist"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#tablist) set on the right element (and possibly `role="tab"` is not set on the right elements.)  Confirm again you're following the design pattern.

When you have `role="tablist"`, that will automatically switch NVDA from "browse mode" (where keyboard events are sent to NVDA) to "forms mode" (where keyboard events are sent to your application).  When keyboard events are sent to your application, the left/right arrow keys should work just like when NVDA is not running.

You can see a list of roles that cause NVDA to switch modes automatically for you at "[Fundamental Keyboard Navigation Conventions](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#x6-1-fundamental-keyboard-navigation-conventions)".  The tab pattern is one of those roles.

You should be able to confirm your left/right arrow keys work by tabbing to your tab navigator with NVDA running then pressing <kbd>INS</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.  That will toggle the "browse mode" to "forms mode" and then your arrow keys should work.